# How to convert an user input to a set in python?

Tags: python, string, set, user-input

I want to make a set from alphabets of a user input for example:
input is: "something" and the output must be: { 's', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'g'}
I wrote it like below but it caused an error saying the input must be iterable!

```
 str = print("please enter a string:")
 str_set = set(str)
 print(str_set)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors:

1. `str` is built-in, so you need a different name.
2. You need `input` to catch the input, not just print.

```
str1 = input("please enter a string:")
str_set = set(str1)
print(str_set)
```

You could also shorten to just one line if you want to be more concise, but when trading concision against readability, lean towards readability:

```
str_set = set(input("please enter a string: "))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to input something from the user you should use the `input()` function:

```py
s = input("please enter a string:")
str_set = set(s)
print(str_set)
```

Comment: I also think that ```s = set(input("please enter a string:"))``` would also work

Comment: @Sujay: Yes, you are correct, but I suspect that the OP wants to make the code work one step at a time so they can check what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all you shouldn't named variables using buildins objects names like: `str, int, float` and so one.
2. `print` function will return `None` and isn't iterable, so you get an error. You should use `input` function instead.

`user_input = input("please enter a string:")`

Answer (score 0):

There are some rules for naming variables, one of which is that you can't use reserved words such as: print, str, int, float, input, etc. for naming your variables.
You can learn more about the rules here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-variables/

And about the code, I believe this would help:

```
    user_input = input("Please enter a string: ")
    list_of_letters = list(user_input)
    print(list_of_letters)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use input instead of print. print is to print something on terminale/ command line, it is also possible to get user input with your script without (str =) like so :

```
import sys

def printerd():
    print('please enter a string:', end='')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    data = sys.stdin.readline()[:-1]
    print(list(data))

 printerd()
```

this will print please enter a string : and wait for user to type something and then print an array ['s', 'o', etc].